# Exists $y \in K$ such that $\|y-x_0\|=\inf\{\|x-x_0\| :x \in K\}$ for disjoint closed sets $K$ and the set of $\{x_0:\|x_0\|≥b\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

$K$ closed, $x_0 \in R^n$. $K \subset B(0,a)$ and $\|x_0\|≥b>a$

I'm looking for the idea behind displaying the existence of

$y \in K$ such that:

$$\|y-x_0\|=\inf\{\|x-x_0\| :x \in K\}$$

which is the shortest length between the space of $x_0$ s.t. $\|x_0\| ≥ 42$ and K.

Comment: What's the norm on $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: You mean *the shortest length between the **point** $x_0$ and $K$*.

Comment: $\sqrt{(y_0 - x_{0_0})^2+...+(y_n - x_{0_n})^2}$

Comment: take a sequence, then take a converging subsequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\delta=\inf\{\|x-x_0\| :x \in K\}$, this implies that there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ in $K$ such that $||x_0-x_n||\to \delta$. Since $K$ is a closed and bounded subset of $\Bbb R^n$, it is compact so there is a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$ such that $x_{n_k}\to x^*\in K$. We then have 
$$
||x^*-x_0||=\lim_{k\to \infty}||x_{n_k}-x_0||= \delta
$$
because $(x_{n_k})$ is a subsequence of $(x_n)$. Take $y=x^*$ and we are done.

Note that this argument work because $\Bbb R^n$ is locally compact, in a general normed space you won't be so lucky like this. Sometimes such a $y$ doesn't exist.

Comment: It's not necessary to say anything else about the infimum? Such as, the infimum exists?

Comment: @mavavilj What do you mean by the infimum really being the infimum?

Comment: Why can we pick $\delta$?

Comment: Assuming that $K$ is non-empty, the set $\{\|x-x_0\| :x \in K\}$ is then a non-empty set bounded below by $0$ so its infimum exists by the completeness of real number.

Comment: @mavavilj Feel free to ask me any question if you're still confused or need more explanation :)